# Audio problems with asus notebook with Bluetooth and usb devices in win 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers

My notebook is

```
Asus P53E - core i5
Windows 7 installed
```

Audio from PC speakers and headphone is distorted when i turn on bluetooth or some usb device plugged in. 
I belive this is a software issue. I tried updating my audio drivers but nothing help. Any help will be appreciated.

Update: After a few days digging I found that this problem is causing by the asus sound enhancement application [SonicFocus](http://support.asus.com/Search/KDetail.aspx?SLanguage=en&no=F35E8592-1650-410F-41D0-ABB9279BBFDA&t=2). The distortion stops while turning off sonic focus. Can anyone help me with a solution other than turning off SonicFocus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And now I have got a solution for my problem. I'm posting it as answer if someone else is having the same.
I just disabled `All Sound Effects` from `Speaker Properties`.
There's no distorted sound while turning `Sonic Focus` on or using `BlueTooth`.
[image]